# Lambda function generating "ambiguous function call" error despite lack of ambiguity

Tags: c++, lambda

So I'm trying to deal with a program that can accept a function that either returns a vector of doubles, or just returns a single double.

Unfortunately, when I try to compile this (MSVC2010) I get the following error:

```
ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

Is there anything I'm doing that's obviously wrong? I need a way to differentiate between the two, and I'm trying to avoid hackish template metaprogramming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> foo(std::function<std::vector<double>(unsigned int) > a){return a(10);}

double foo(std::function<double(unsigned int) > a){return a(11);}

int main(){
    foo([](unsigned int)->double{return 12.0;});
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, my return type is explicitly declared to be a double, yet it can't decide which version of `foo` to call.

Should I just run back to function pointers?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Compiles fine on GCC 4.9

Comment: After some more diligent research, it looks like MSVC2010 doesn't allow for conversion from lambda function to function pointer or `std::function`. Oh well, would've been nice. Maybe I'll get around to getting Visual Studio 2013... Thanks though! Good to know I'm not thinking illogically.

Comment: MSVC2010. C++11. I want to believe...